# Code works, but getting strange error from file I'm not allowed to change

Tags: java

The error is coming from when I try to run the AnagramMainGUI.java. I can change `Word.java` and `AnagramManager.java` but CANNOT CHANGE `AnagramMainGUI.java`.

This is the Word class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Word implements Comparable<Word>
{
   private String word;
   private String canonical;

   public Word(String word)
   {
      String lowerCase = word.toLowerCase();
      this.word = lowerCase;
      canonical = CanonicalForm(word);
   }

   public String getWord()
   {
      return word;
   }

   public String getForm()
   {
      return canonical;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return "[" + word + "=" + canonical + "]";
   }

   public int compareTo(Word someWord)
   {
      return getForm().compareTo(someWord.getForm());
   }

   private static String CanonicalForm(String word)
   {
      if(word == null || word.length() < 1) 
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      char arr[] = word.toCharArray();
      Arrays.sort(arr);
      return new String(arr);
   }
}
```

This is the AnagramManager class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class AnagramManager
{
   private Word[] words;
   private Random rand;
   private Map<String,Set<String>> theMap;

   public AnagramManager(List<String> list)
   {
      if (list == null || list.size() < 1)
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      rand = new Random();
      words = new Word[list.size()];
      theMap = new TreeMap<String,Set<String>>();

      makeWords(list);
      makeAnagrams();
   }

   public void sortByWord()
   {
      for (Word i : words)
      {
         i.getWord();
      }
      Arrays.sort(words);
   }

   public void sortByForm()
   {
      for(Word c : words)
      {
         c.getForm();
      }
      Arrays.sort(words);
   }

   public String getAnagram(String word)
   {
      String canonWord = CanonicalForm(word);
      if(theMap.containsKey(canonWord))
      {
         Set<String> anagramSet = theMap.get(canonWord);
         String[] match = anagramSet.toArray(new String[anagramSet.size()]);
         return match[rand.nextInt(match.length)];
      }
      else
      {
         return "";
      }
   }

   public Set<String> getAnagrams(String word)
   {
      String canonWord = CanonicalForm(word);
      boolean hasAnagram = theMap.containsKey(canonWord);

      Set<String> anagrams = (hasAnagram) ? theMap.get(canonWord) : new TreeSet<String>();


      return anagrams;
   }


   public String toString()
   {
      String printWords = "";
      int length = words.length;

      if (length < 1)
      {
         printWords += "[]";
      }
      else
      {

         for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
         {
            printWords += words[i];
         }

         printWords += "[...]";

         for(int i = length - 5; i < length; i++)
         {
            printWords += words[i];
         }
      }
      return printWords;
   }         

   private static String CanonicalForm(String word)
   {
      if(word == null || word.length() < 1)
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      char arr[] = word.toCharArray();
      Arrays.sort(arr);
      return new String(arr);
   }

   private void makeWords(List<String> list)
   {
      int ind = 0;

      for (String orgWord : list)
      {
         words[ind] = new Word(orgWord);
         ind++;
      }
   }

   private void makeAnagrams()
   {
      for(Word i : words)
      {
         String canon = i.getForm();
         String org = i.getWord();

         if(!theMap.containsKey(canon))
         {
            Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
            set.add(org);
            theMap.put(canon,set);
         }
         else
         {
            theMap.get(canon).add(org);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and here is the AnagramMainGUI class:

```
// CS 145 ASSIGNMENT 5
// GUI INTERFACE

import java.awt.*; // for Dimension
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; // for GUI components 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

/** CS145
 * Class AnagramMainGUI is the driver program for the Anagram program.  It reads a
 * dictionary of words to be used during the game and then asks the user to create a
 * data structure to sort through them.
 *
 * <p>This version uses a GUI to force students to not have access to the console.
 *
 * <p><B>
 * STUDENTS SHOULD NOT MODIFY THIS PROGRAM IN ANY WAY.
 * </B>
 * @author Michael A. Wood
 * @version 1.0
 */

public class AnagramMainGUI implements ActionListener  
{
   // Dictionary File name.
    public static final String DICTIONARY_FILE = "dictionary.txt";

    // GUI ELEMENTS
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button1;
    private JTextField edit1;
    private JLabel text1;
    private JLabel text2;
    private JTextArea text3;
    private JTextArea text4;    

    private JLabel sortW;
    private JLabel sortF;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane3;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane4;
    private JCheckBox debugMode;
    private List<String> dictionary;
    private List<String> dictionary2;
    private AnagramManager catalog;

    /**  Main Program.
     *
     * @param args The OS parameters
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
       AnagramMainGUI gui = new AnagramMainGUI();
    }

    /** The constructor that preps the GUI and all its components
     *
     */
    public AnagramMainGUI()
    {

        // Call private method to set up the form.
        formSetup();

        // Open the file and read the words into the dictionary.
        // Lower case as going.
        try{
           Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(DICTIONARY_FILE));
           dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
           while (input.hasNext()) {
              dictionary.add(input.next().toLowerCase());
           }
         }
         catch (FileNotFoundException e)
         {
           // Exit the program after outputing error to both console and Dialog box.
           System.out.println("File not found error :  " + e);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File not found error :  " + e); 
           System.exit(0);
         }

        // set up the AnagramManager
        // Create an unmodifiable dictionary list to pass to the manager
        // the manager is called catalog.
        dictionary2 = Collections.unmodifiableList(dictionary);
        catalog = new AnagramManager(dictionary2);

        // Show the debugging data.
        // This is where the sorting is needed.
        catalog.sortByWord();
        text3.setText(catalog.toString());
        catalog.sortByForm();
        text4.setText(catalog.toString()); 

        // Open the frame.        
        frame.setVisible(true);

     }  

     /**
      * This method responds to all events thrown by the various elements
      * of the GUI
      * @param event The action event thrown by the GUI
      */
     @Override 
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
     {
       //  If button is pressed or enter is pressed while the edit box has focus.
       if (event.getActionCommand().equals("FindAnagram"))
       {
        // Get the text from the edit box.
         String x = edit1.getText();
         String y;
         // Use the AnagramManager HERE
         String result = catalog.getAnagram(x);
         // if the result is blank
         if (!result.equals("") )
            y = "One possible anagram of the word " + x + " is     ::  " + result;
         else
            y = "Your word was not found in the list";
         // Display the output.
         text1.setText(y);

         // Show the list of anagrams.
          String z = "In fact the list of anagrams for the word are    :: ";
          z+= catalog.getAnagrams(x);
          text2.setText(z);
       }      
       if (event.getActionCommand().equals("debugMode"))
       {
          // Display the neccessary debuging tools
          scrollPane3.setVisible(debugMode.isSelected());
          scrollPane4.setVisible(debugMode.isSelected()); 
          sortW.setVisible(debugMode.isSelected());
          sortF.setVisible(debugMode.isSelected()); 

          // Resize the window.
          if (debugMode.isSelected())
             frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 300));
          else
              frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 150));             

       }
     }

     // Commands to set up the form.   
     // Note that the form must still be set to visible.
     // This does everything but that.
     private void formSetup()
     {
        // GUI SETUP
        // Window setup.      
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(new Point(100, 500));
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 150));
        frame.setTitle("Anagrams");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
        // Find Anagram button
        button1 = new JButton();
        button1.setText("Find Anagram");
        button1.addActionListener(this );
        button1.setActionCommand("FindAnagram");
        // User input Edit Field
        edit1 = new JTextField();
        edit1.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 24 ) );
        edit1.setActionCommand("FindAnagram");
        edit1.addActionListener(this );

        // Output Text Fields
        text1 = new JLabel();
        text1.setText("NOTHING");
        text2 = new JLabel();
        text2.setText("NOTHING");
        text3 = new JTextArea();
        text3.setText("NOTHING");
        text4 = new JTextArea();
        text4.setText("NOTHING");  

        // Debugging Tools        
        scrollPane3 = new JScrollPane(text3);
        scrollPane4 = new JScrollPane(text4);
        scrollPane3.setVisible(false);
        scrollPane4.setVisible(false);
        sortW = new JLabel();
        sortW.setText("Sorted by Word");  
        sortF = new JLabel();
        sortF.setText("Sorted by Form");  
        sortW.setVisible(false);        
        sortF.setVisible(false);        

        // Debugging Radio Button
        debugMode = new JCheckBox();
        debugMode.setText("Debug Mode");
        debugMode.addActionListener(this );
        debugMode.setActionCommand("debugMode");

        // Add components to frame.
        frame.add(button1);
        frame.add(edit1);
        frame.add(text1);
        frame.add(text2);
        frame.add(scrollPane3);
        frame.add(scrollPane4);
        frame.add(debugMode);
        frame.add(sortW);
        frame.add(sortF);

        // Layout the frame.
        // null layout to demonstrate the idea.   
        // not using the default layouts to show the idea.
        frame.setLayout(null); 
        edit1.setBounds (185, 10, 200, 25);
        button1.setBounds(10,10,150,25);
        text1.setBounds(10, 50, 750,25);
        text2.setBounds(10, 80, 750,25);
        sortW.setBounds(10, 110, 100,40);
        sortF.setBounds(10, 180, 1000,40);
        scrollPane3.setBounds(115, 110, 650,40);
        scrollPane4.setBounds(115, 180, 650,40);
        debugMode.setBounds(400, 10, 100,25);


        // Inline function to set focus on the edit box. 
        frame.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() 
                                     { public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) 
                                       {edit1.requestFocusInWindow();}
                                     });


     }
}
```

Here is the error:

> ```
> AnagramMainGUI.java:158: error: constructor Point in class Point cannot be applied to given types;
>         frame.setLocation(new Point(100, 500));
>                           ^
>   required: no arguments
>   found: int,int
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
> 1 error
> ```

```
/* CS145
 * Class AnagramMain is the driver program for the Anagram program.  It reads a
 * dictionary of words to be used during the game and then asks the user to create a
 * data structure to sort through them.
 */


import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class AnagramMain {
    public static final String DICTIONARY_FILE = "dictionary.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the CS145 Anagram Practice");
        System.out.println();

        // open the dictionary file and read dictionary into an ArrayList
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(DICTIONARY_FILE));
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            dictionary.add(input.next().toLowerCase());
        }

        // set up the AnagramManager
        List<String> dictionary2 = Collections.unmodifiableList(dictionary);
        AnagramManager catalog = new AnagramManager(dictionary2);

      // Start the program asking for run style
      System.out.println("Press enter to start, or any other input for debug mode");
      String DEBUG = keyboard.nextLine();

      // If in DEBUG mode
      if (!DEBUG.equals("") )
      {
        System.out.println("** The first and last five sorted by word elements are **");
        catalog.sortByWord();
        System.out.println(catalog);
        System.out.println("** The first and last five sorted by form elements are **");
        catalog.sortByForm();
        System.out.println(catalog);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n");
      }

      // Start the Loop
      getAnagram(keyboard, catalog);

    }

    // Executes the primary anagram loop
    public static void getAnagram(Scanner console, AnagramManager theCatalog) 
   {
      String input;
      System.out.println("Please type in a word to anagram or QUIT to quit :");
      input = console.nextLine();

      while (!input.toUpperCase().equals("QUIT") && !input.equals("") ) 
      {
        String result = theCatalog.getAnagram(input);
        if (!result.equals("") )
        {
         System.out.print("One possible anagram of your word " + input );
         System.out.println(" is " +result);
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println("Your word was not found in the list");
        }

        System.out.print("In fact the list of anagrams for your word are : ");
        System.out.println(theCatalog.getAnagrams(input));

        System.out.println("Please type in a word to anagram or QUIT to quit :");
        input = console.nextLine();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is saying your `Point` class is a missing a 2-arg constructor.

Comment: Since it appears that the AnagramMainGUI class is supposed to compile ok "elsewhere", it follows that your use of it is somehow using a different definition of the Point class.  Presumably [java.awt.Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) is what is required.

Comment: but doesn't java.awt.*; take care of that?

Comment: also i cant make any changes to AnagramMainGUI so im not sure what to do instead

Comment: I commented out everything in AnagramMainGUI() except formSetup(); and frame.setVisible(true); (also commented out the ActionListener code and calls). The JFrame became visible, no errors. Maybe you should try the same and see if the error goes away. Given that this is an assignment and shouldn't be altered, chances are there is some sort of configuration snafu, but I don't know what it would be. Main technique I know for tracking this sort of thing down is to keep honing it down and make progressively smaller versions that raise the same error. Usually something arises. If not, ask teacher!

Comment: The offending line of code would normally be fine, if we were in truth dealing with JFrame as a subclass of Window (which is where setLocation(Point) resides, and awt.Point(int, int). May I ask what IDE and Java version you are using?

Comment: Well in the assignment, we were told to create Word and AnagramManager, and to make sure that they worked for two separate files. One of them was AnagramMainGUI. The other was AnagramMain, which i got to work just fine.

Comment: I added AnagramMain. Don't know if that answers any questions.

Comment: You code as it is works, so this is likely due to your environment or how you compiling and running it. Add this to your question.

Comment: I know right? My code seems fine and works perfectly for AnagramMain but not for AnagramMainGUI.